# Why does Angular Material use alpha to create grey colors?

Tags: angular-material2

I've noticed that in angular material when they need a grey they take black and then adjust it's alpha to be lighter. For example if you go here: https://material.angular.io/components and inspect any of the cards on the page, you'll notice the body paragraph has the font color `rgba(0, 0, 0, .54);`. Does anyone know why they choose to create greys by taking black and adjusting the alpha this way as opposed to just using hex or rgb? The only thing I can think of is that it helps support the warm and cool themes.

Comment: so that the color looks correct whether, e.g, it's on a pure white or light gray background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-usability

> **Do:** Using opacity instead of shifting colors often creates better contrast and relative luminance. For example, gray text (#727272) becomes hard to read if the background color changes to magenta.

[image]

> **Don't:** Shifting to gray instead of decreasing contrast on black often lowers the relative luminance, making typography unreadable.

[image]